# Laravel sort by a relationship in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Many to many relationship between users and reports. Any user can have many reports. I want to sort the reports for a user by the created_at column. How would i finish this below to do that??

```
$x = User::find(1)->report.....
```

For anyone wondering, you add parenthesis to the end of a relationship method when you are chaining on a function like orderBy() you leave it off when you just want the collection. IF you need to alter the returned collection by sorting or something you would add parenthesis because you are in fact ADDING(CHAINING) another method behind the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = User::find(1)->reports()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

See the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset). Also [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

From the second link:

> Once the relationship is defined, you may access the user's roles using the roles dynamic property:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    //
}
```

> Of course, like all other relationship types, you may call the roles method to continue chaining query constraints onto the relationship:

```
$roles = App\User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: Yea i figured it out FYI neither link will help anyone if they actually had this problem. Knowing what many to many relationships are and what orderBy did isn't helping. DIFFERENTIATING between report and report() is. Neither link mentions the difference. Its not helpful to throw a bunch of links up for reference just because its the laravel docs. Stackoverflow is notorious for users doing this when it doesn't help or add to the solution

Comment: Please see my edit which shows the relevant parts of the doc which does explain it. Please also consider upvoting and/or accepting answers.